# Node.js: Socket.io emit method not firing

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to use socket.io to have a client send a message to the server and then the server then sends some info back. Here's what my code looks like

#### Server Side

```
let app = express();
let server = app.listen(3000);
app.use(express.static('public'));

let socket = require('socket.io');
let io = socket(server);

let playerData = [[],[],[],[],[]];
io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => { 
    console.log(socket.id);
    socket.on("joinRoom",(data) =>{
         socket.join(data.room);
         console.log("recieved join request by socket: " + socket.id + " " + data.class);
         let intRoom = parseInt(data.room) // parses what room to join (from string to int)
         socket.to(data.room).emit('newJoin', {id: socket.id, class: data.class}); // Tells room that a new user has joined 
         socket.emit("success", "You have succesfully joined a lobby");
         socket.emit('addPlayers', playerData[intRoom]) // Sends player the data of all other players in the room 
         playerData[intRoom]
         playerData[intRoom].push(data.player);
    })
})
```

#### Client Side

```
    if(enteringRoom){ 
// This if statement is being run every frame 
        if(player.loaded){
            console.log('telling server to join room'); // This Fires 
            socket.emit('joinRoom', {room: lobbySelect.value, class: characterSelect.value, player: player});
            enteringRoom = false;
        }
        camera.position.x = 0; // updates the position of a camera
        camera.position.z = -50;
    }
socket.on('newJoin', (data) => {
    console.log('someone has joined the room');
    console.log(data);
})
socket.on('success', (res) =>{
    console.log(res);
})
socket.on('addPlayers', (data) => {
    console.log("Adding Players...");
    for(let i = 0; i< data.length; i++){
        console.log[i];
        console.log("ADDING A PLAYER");
        console.log(data[i]);
        data[i].loadAssets();
        playersInLobby += 1;
    }
    console.log(playersInLobby);
})
```

The problem is that nothing in the `joinRoom` event actually activates on the server end. None of the console logs even go off. The server however is able to `console.log` the `socket.id` on connection; that part works. Any ideas why it's not working?

Edit: This also causes the browser tab to freeze up and eventually crash

Comment: In Client side are you pointing the "socket" to the socket created on your server properly?

Comment: I believe so, at the top of the program I put in 
"let socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/');"

Comment: Any chance you're trying to do `socket.emit('joinRoom', ...)` before the client has finished connecting to the server?  Are you monitoring the `connect` event on the client?

Comment: How would I check for this? I have the server console log upon a connection - which it successfully does. Does that work?

Comment: On the client side you can listen for the connection to the server as well `socket.on('connect', function () { console.log('connected'); });` 

Usually, I wrap my other socket listeners within that function. Check that this gets called client side.